# Python Twiested, where to read client input

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following code:

```
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.


"""
An example client. Run simpleserv.py first before running this.
"""

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol


# a client protocol

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
"""Once connected, send a message, then print the result."""

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("Welcome to Calculator!")
        # data = ''

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        print "Server said:\n", data
        # self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "connection lost"

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()


# this connects the protocol to a server running on port 8000
def main():
    help(protocol.Protocol)
    exit()
    f = EchoFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000, f)
    reactor.run()

    print 'here'

# this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is the correct way to read client input and send it to server? I want to read the data using `data = input()` and after it send to server `self.transport.write(data)`. But, where I have to put it on my code, do I have to create another method or use `connectionMade`?
Remembering, that is a persistent connection where client send something to server, then the server process it and send something to client. And again client send something to server, server process it and send to client... (repeatedly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def connectionMade(self):
        # Asks user for their name
        name = input('What is your name?')
        # sends name to server
        self.transport.write(name)
```

This will be speicifc to each client/connection, so you should only have one connectionMade method.

Comment: Danny Culle, why on initial connection, this method (connectionMade), is called 4 times?

Comment: As long as you call EchoClient only once, then you should have one per connection you make

Comment: You need to design a protocol for this kind of action, so that the client and server and talk backwards and forwards depending on your rules.

Comment: Thanks Danny Cullen, I'm newbie on Twisted, can you post a question or show me a link to a tutorial that creates a protocal that I  nedd?

Comment: http://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-16.1.1/core/howto/servers.html#putting-it-all-together - take a look at the chat.py example